# Default.ctp and a totally different login page

Tags: css, cakephp, view

Within my default.ctp page I keep navigational and structural content applicable to the entire application. For example menu structures and a column based CSS. I would like to change my login page, however, to look entirely different (no menu, no columns, etc)

Is there a way to load a separate ctp file for a single URL only? e.g. /plugin/controller/login

Answer (score 2):

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views.html

You can create a new layout for the login page and for that controller/action change the layout name

```
$this->layout = 'login';
```

Comment: Worth clarifying that you can do that in the controller **or** the view file.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways. First, you create your new layout file, à la `login.ctp` inside your `View/Layout` folder.

Next, in your `login` action, at the top you can write `$this->layout = "login";`. The other way you can do it is when you render the view, at the end of your action method, like this: `$this->render('actionName', 'login');`